# Where did they get the name for Star Trek’s Q?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-voyager, inspiration

What inspired the god-like being Q introduced in Star Trek:The Next Generation *Encounter at Farpoint*? Where did the show's creators get the name and inspiration for Q's character?

Comment: The inspiration for Q was (according to MA), to bulk out the pilot episode's original plotline (*Enterprise goes to new starbase, weird stuff happens, fin*) into a 2 hour special.

Comment: @Valorum *ST:Discovery*'s Klingons are among the best things *ever* in the *ST* franchise. Come at me!

Comment: They break all the rules. https://thesffblog.com/2016/01/the-13-commandments-from-the-tng-bible/

Comment: STD. LOL. First time seeing the pun

Comment: @VogonPoet - And yet, so very very accurate

Comment: They broke with that on TOS as well: how many god-like beings did Kirk and crew meet over the course of TOS? Greek gods and other god-like entities are met with alarming regularity throughout the voyages of the original Enterprise...

Comment: The Talosians were fairly god-like, and technically speaking, they were in the first pilot. In the secon pilot, Gary Mitchell became god like as well

Comment: @JackBNimble "They break all the rules." Right, so you are saying that *ST:Discovery* is *art*.

Comment: @NKCampbell Not to mention the Organians and the entity from "The Squire of Gothos."

Answer (score 6):

The character Q played by actor John de Lancie in the character's debut in the Star Trek:The Next Generation pilot, *Encounter at Farpoint* was inspired by a long-time British fan of the franchise named Janet Quarton. In the early 1970's Brittain there were only a few fan followings available and all seemed to fall short of the enthusiasm Ms. Quarton had for the show. She recalls [in issue #100 of her newsletter](https://fanlore.org/wiki/A_History_of_Star_Trek_Action_Group_by_Janet_Quarton) that

> When I found out about Star Trek fandom in 1972 there was only one specific Star Trek club in Britain: The Star Trek Correspondence Club run by Audrey Baker. There was also The William Shatner Fan Club and The Scottish Society for Leonard Nimoy Fanatics

~ *A History of Star Trek Action Group* by Janet Quarton

[image: Star Trek Action Group newsletter]

The fan club was originally started after Star Trek: The Animated Series began releasing in 1973. The idea started with Jenny and Terry Elson who were attempting to raise money for a full-fledged British Star Trek fan convention. That newsletter was called the *Star Trek Con for Britain Action Group*, and Janet became its second member, and then its first president, serving in that role for 8 years.

> I joined STAG as soon as I saw it advertised and was always proud of my membership number -- no. 2.

As the club was designed to do, it was incredibly successful in funding and launching the first ever British Star Trek fan convention on September 28 & 29 in 1974. Her guests of honor were Scotty (Jimmy Doohan) and Sulu (George Takei) at the Abbey Motor Hotel in Leicester.

Later in 1975 Ms. Quarton co-founded a fanzine called *ScoTpress* which went on to print 145 zines between 1975 and 1996.

In 1977 Gene Roddenberry, his wife Majel, and their young son were in Great Britain filming *Spectre* and on February 1st, Mr. Roddenberry called Janet asking for her and 50 fans to join him at the set.

In 1978 Mr. Roddenberry sent Janet a telegram announcing that the whole cast was getting together again for the production of *Star Trek: The Motion Picture*. This gave her controlled inside information making her newsletters and zines immensely popular.

Janet went on to raise money for conventions while also donating a portion of the proceeds to charities. Notably, at the 1981 Stag Con which she organized they raised £1200 for the Guide Dogs for the Blind Association, and adopted a guide dog named Quanta.

In considering production for the Star Trek: The Next Generation Gene Roddenberry gave the protagonistic omnipotent character the name Q in honor of his loyal fan and her unearthly powers to promote the franchise in a new market.

Comment: This is a *really* good answer to the 'name and inspiration' bit of your question, but 'powers to promote the franchise' seems a tad different than 'omnipotence.'

Comment: Nice story - but do you actually have source for the last paragraph?

Comment: @HorusKol Wikipedia has broad corroboration [since December 2004](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Q_(Star_Trek)&diff=8951021&oldid=8737457); [in 2011 it was amended](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?diff=435794128) to cite p536 of David Alexander's [_Star trek creator : the authorized biography of Gene Roddenberry_](https://archive.org/details/startrekcreator00davi). I can't check it out right now to verify, but it's something to go on.

Comment: @JeffBowman fair enough - just wanted to see if there was more evidence than "Gene knew somebody whose name starts with a Q"